# $ABC$ is a triangle right angled at $B$. $D$ is a point on $AC$ such that $\angle ABD = \pi/4$. If $AC = 6$ and $AD = 2$, then $AB$ is

Tags: trigonometry

I've solved this question but I'm not getting the right answer.

I assumed the radius of the in-circle of the triangle to be $r$.

As tangents drawn from the same point to a circle are equal, I get the equation :

$$(r+2)^2 + (r+4)^2 = 36$$

On solving this I get an answer that my math teacher claims is wrong. Can anyone tell me what I'm doing wrong ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

$BD$ is angle bisector of angle $B$

Using bisector theorem we have:

$$\frac{BC}{4}=\frac{AB}{2} \Rightarrow BC=2AB$$

Pythagoras Theorem:

$$6^2=AB^2+BC^2 \Rightarrow 36=5AB^2 \Rightarrow AB=6\sqrt{5}/5$$